# RestResource Class: Set the HTTP Response Status in APEX

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, rest-service, httpresponse

We have exposed an Apex Class as a Rest Resource. It is a HTTP Post class and broadly it has the following logic:

1. Get parameters to create a new Account
2. Validate if existing database if it is a duplicate
3. If yes, throw error.
4. If no, create Account and return the Salesforce ID of the Account.

The response is returned in a JSON format. What I want is to also be able to set the HTTP Response Status parameter. It is by default set by Salesforce as 200 but I want to set it based on various conditions in my logic (For e.g.: 400 in step 3 on above logic).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
```

You can set any status code defined in [RestResponse](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm); simply set RestContext.response.statusCode to any value you'd like from the following list:

```
200 OK
201 CREATED
202 ACCEPTED
204 NO_CONTENT
206 PARTIAL_CONTENT
300 MULTIPLE_CHOICES
301 MOVED_PERMANENTLY
302 FOUND
304 NOT_MODIFIED
400 BAD_REQUEST
401 UNAUTHORIZED
403 FORBIDDEN
404 NOT_FOUND
405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
406 NOT_ACCEPTABLE
409 CONFLICT
410 GONE
412 PRECONDITION_FAILED
413 REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE
414 REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE
415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
417 EXPECTATION_FAILED
500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
503 SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
```